# Class for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch] not implement [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I am getting the following error when I startup Spring web application in Tomcat.

Basically, as the beans.xml file is processed, the following classes are loaded in order.

org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler to process URI   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler to process URI  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util

org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler to process URI  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws

org.apache.cxf.transport.http.spring.NamespaceHandler to process URI  http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration

org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespaceHandler to process URI  http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch

But when it is loading the above last class for batch URI, the following Exception occurs.

```
12/28/2017-11:21:47.070 - localhost-startStop-1 - ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader : Line 227]: Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
```

I looked into the source of all the above classes and found that all of them extend

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport
```

which in turn implements

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler
```

I have checked the jars on classpath and they look fine, containing the above classes and interfaces in respective, expected spring jar files.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Similar questions are here and I have tried whats given there.

[Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [config/FaceBookSimulator.xml];](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068558/unexpected-exception-parsing-xml-document-from-class-path-resource-config-faceb)

and

[Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523997/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-http-www-sp)

**Update**

I restarted Tomcat with -verbose:class option to print all classes being loaded form whichever jar files. And I found the following:

```
12/28/2017-15:01:18.251 - localhost-startStop-1 - DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver : Line 156]: Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings:{
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration=org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.spring.PolicyNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws=org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/policy=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/transports/jms=org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration=org.apache.cxf.transport.http.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/object=org.apache.cxf.binding.object.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing=org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/clustering=org.apache.cxf.clustering.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/simple=org.apache.cxf.frontend.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/core=org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/binding/coloc=org.apache.cxf.binding.coloc.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.spring.PolicyNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms=org.springframework.jms.config.JmsNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespaceHandler, 
 http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.spring.PolicyNamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/ws/rm/manager=org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.spring.NamespaceHandler, 
 http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.spring.NamespaceHandler
}
```

The class

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver
```

is processing:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespaceHandler
```

The DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver does not extend NamespaceHandlerSupport ( which implements NamespaceHandler).

If the finding is right, how to resolve this?

Comment: Most likely you have a classloader hierarchy problem.  The failing class is being loaded by a classloader that is different from the one that loaded the interface.

Comment: Jim, I have added an update, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

My application was relying on shared jar files on the server lib directory. There are many jars over. I needed to sort out the service side jar files. But the quickest solution was to package the needed jars within the WEB-INF/lib of the WAR file.